# AngularJS expression $scope is not being evaluated in the template html

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am able to console.log all the values correctly, but the expression img ng-src="{{$scope.bus}}" is not being evaluated. I am very new to angularJs, any help would be great. Below is the code

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function (ev, bus) {

      $scope.bus = bus;
      console.log(bus);
      console.log("scope.bus ="+$scope.bus);
      $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        template: '<div role="dialog" aria-label="Eat me!" layout="column" layout-align="center center">' +
          '    <md-toolbar>' +
          '      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">' +
          '        <h2>Surprise!</h2>' +
          '      </div>' +
          '    </md-toolbar>' +
          '  ' +
          '   <div ' +
          '    <div id="slideDiv" class="demo-dialog-content">' +
          '      <div layout="row" >' +
          '        <img ng-src="{{$scope.bus}}">' +
          '      </div>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '  ' +
          '    <div layout="row" class="demo-dialog-button">' +
          '      <md-button md-autofocus flex class="md-primary" ng-click="cancel()">' +
          '        Close' +
          '      </md-button>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '  </div>',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
      })
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried `<img ng-src="{{bus}}">` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Its not working too

Answer (score 0):

$scope will not work in this case as it is an isolated one. Can you try adding *locals*. Thanks.

```
locals: {bus: $scope.bus}
```

or

Following in the first method.

```
locals: {parent: $scope}
```

Comment: isolateScope: false can you try this then?

Comment: Any expression inside {{}} is not evaluated. I don't seem to understand why

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function (ev, bus) {

      $scope.bus = bus;
      console.log(bus);
      console.log("scope.bus ="+$scope.bus);
      $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        controllerAs: 'DialogCtrl',
        template: '<div role="dialog" aria-label="Eat me!" layout="column" layout-align="center center">' +
          '    <md-toolbar>' +
          '      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">' +
          '        <h2>Surprise!</h2>' +
          '      </div>' +
          '    </md-toolbar>' +
          '  ' +
          '   <div ' +
          '    <div id="slideDiv" class="demo-dialog-content">' +
          '      <div layout="row" >' +
          '        <img ng-src="{{DialogCtrl.bus}}">' +
          '      </div>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '  ' +
          '    <div layout="row" class="demo-dialog-button">' +
          '      <md-button md-autofocus flex class="md-primary" ng-click="cancel()">' +
          '        Close' +
          '      </md-button>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '  </div>',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
      })
    };
```